# jQuery accordion plugin "active" problem

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

i'm using [jquery accordion plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-accordion/). in this plugin first clickable menu element is already selected and active. i want all clickable elements are closed in accordion. how can i do this? i try "active: false" and "alwaysOpen: false" but not working. sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Please accept answers on questions you ask. It seems unlikely that all of your 6 questions didn't have a suitable answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the jqueryui documentation, you need to set `collapsible` to `true` when you initialise it:

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({ collapsible: true });
```

The example is from the jQueryUI documentation.

Comment: this worked for me only when i put the collapsible option directly after the active option.

Answer (score 2):

`$( ".selector" ).accordion({ collapsible: true, active: false });`

make sure you write collapsible: true first and then active: false

Answer (score 1):

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({ collapsible: true, active: false });
```

Make sure both options are present.

Answer (score 0):

Use `false` in `active` http://jsfiddle.net/q8aYH/ . But `collapsible` to `true` is 'true' method...

Comment: yes i know this solution but this is not working on my structure. actually your structure is same with mine. but not working. there is a problem i know but i can't see what is.

Answer (score 0):

I solved. The problem caused by jQuery version. i'm using 1.3.2 i changed with 1.5 it fixed.